# file doesn,t found in c language when i use goto label to again run code without exiting from the output

Tags: c

When i run this code it runs perfectly but when it again comes to label and than 5 files does not found after that i again come from label than all files does not found

```
void main()
{

    int i,a;

    char filepath[100],filename[100];

    FILE *fp;

    clrscr();

    label:

    clrscr();
    printf("Press 1:");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    if(a==1)
    {
        for(i=1;i<10;i++)
        {
            sprintf(filename,"%d",i);
            strcat(filename,".txt");

            fp=fopen(filename,"r");
            if(fp==NULL)
            {
                printf("File not found!!\n");
            }
            printf("%s\n",filename);

        }
        getch();
    }
    else
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    goto label;
}
```

Comment: Can you re-word your problem please?

Comment: when i run this program all files are readable but after its goes goto label and again come top and than i press1`than some files not found

Comment: This is not your actual code. You have `#include <stdio.h>` in your actual code; without it, this will not compile. You also need `#include <string.h>`, and whatever header declares the `getch()` function. Always copy-and-paste your *exact* code into the question -- and format it as code (highlight and select the **{}** button). `void main()` should be `int main(void)`; if your textbook told you to use `void main()` find a better one, written by someone who knows C. There's no need to use `goto`; a loop would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies within the closing of the files.
In the `for(i=1;i<10;i++)` loop you open 9 files, file `1.txt` to file `9.txt`. After you have looped through all the files you only call `fclose(fp);` once. The file you are now closing is file `9.txt`. The other 8 files where never closed.

Change your loop to something like this:

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++)
{
    sprintf(filename,"%d",i);
    strcat(filename,".txt");

    fp=fopen(filename,"r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
         printf("File not found!!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n",filename);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Now you open the file, when it exists, you can use the file and after that close the file.

the `fclose(fp);` right above your `goto label;` can be removed

Comment: In case this worked, would you like to mark this as the answer?